# OpenLayers Locator proximity search(content) and map display within tab

Tags: javascript

I got correct result when i based on  search with mile and distance.

Output displayed openlayer content views and map .

[image]

I need to displayed result like tab view that List and Map both are tab titles

```
 Click list -> displayed  ** Content **
 Click Map  -> displayed  ** Map **
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway I Find Out Solution.
Create a two pages like Page 1 and Page 2.

Setting Menu Tab to both pages

```
1. Menu Tab: List in PAGE SETTINGS
2. Menu Tab: Map in PAGE SETTINGS
```

Change CSS setting in view-filter.
[image: List and Map setting in view]

[image]